# How to get certain row of grouped data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame which could be approximated by the following example:

```
z <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,2) 
y <- c(2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5)
a <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,7,7,7)
x <- data.frame(z,y,a)
```

What I want to do is that to extract each third row of each group grouped by column y and a in a new data frame.
I only was able to come up with code that drag the last row of each group.

```
df1<-ddply(df1, .(y,a), transform, nrow=nrow(z))
df1n<-array(0,c(0,3))
for (i in 1:nrow(x))
{
    df1n <- rbind(df1n, x[x[1,"nrow"],])
    x <- x[-(1:x[i-i+1,"nrow"]),]
    i=i+1
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Please regard y as :

```
y <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,5,5,5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a good use for `by` perhaps

```
do.call(rbind, by(x, list(x$y, x$a), function(z) z[3,]))
```

Just make sure each group has at least three rows. The `do.call(rbind, )` part just merges together the list of data.frames that `by` creates.

Comment: Good answer (+1). The OP is asking to group by both `y` and `a`, though, so you should group by `list(x$y, x$a)` instead.

Comment: @josilber Good point. I missed that part of the question. I have updated my example based on your comment.

Comment: Yes, true .Thank you a lot both of you, that was reason I edited my post. My greetings. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

another solution with dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
newdf <-
x %.%
  group_by(y,a) %.%
  summarize(z = z[3])
```

result:

```
  y a z
1 2 1 2
2 2 2 5
3 4 6 4
4 5 7 2
```

only the order of the columns is different in this case

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, list(z = z[3]), by = c("y", "a")]

##    y a z
## 1: 2 1 2
## 2: 2 2 5
## 3: 4 6 4
## 4: 5 7 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
 df <- x[seq(1, nrow(x), by=3),]
```

which assumes you want the first row, then the fourth, and so on. It can be adjusted to accommodate other requirements.